# Angular - how to make a an option field (with ng-repeat) depend on previously chosen value in option field?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I have 3 fields.
1st - option field / ng-repeat over available dates
2nd - option field / based on the date chosen by user, I do ng-repeat over quantity. I have tried all different ways but I can't make it depend on the first option field or other things don't work. Any help would be great! Thanks !!

html:

```
<div class="containerDiv">
        <div>
            <select ng-model='date'>
                <option ng-repeat="availableDateProduct in product " value='{{i}}'>{{availableDateProduct.dateOfActivity}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="availableDateProduct in product ">
            <select>
                <option ng-repeat='i in quantityLister(availableDateProduct.quantity)' value='{{i}}'>
                    {{i}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>Book</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
    app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, ProductsFactory, $stateParams) {

        ProductsFactory.fetchByTitle($stateParams.title)
            .then(function(product) {
                $scope.product = product;
            })
        $scope.quantityLister = function(num) {
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                array.push(i)
            }
            return array;
        }
    })
```

data:

```
var products = [
  {
    title:'Bowling',
    description:'Its fun!',
    photoUrl:'https://www.1.jpg',
    quantity:12,
    price:9,
    dateOfActivity: '2017-13-07'
  },
...
]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?  The way the question is written right now, it's not really clear, especially since you say "based on the date, I repeat over quantity".  Dates and quantities aren't interchangeable.

Comment: I updated my question with the data. thanks!

Comment: ok, so the first dropdown has, what, the `dateOfActivity`?  then you want to do what with that?  filter the array using that `dateOfActivity`, and display the `quantity` of each item that's filtered?  what does selecting that second dropdown even mean?  how am I supposed to know that `12` means I'm getting the bowling object?  It's still really not obvious what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: so the first dropdown has multiple date and then EACH date has a different quantity. So lets say you pick date 06/05/2017 you get quantity of 6 (tickets for that date) if you pick 08/07/2017 you get 3 tickets (quantity=3) and so on.

Comment: So then wouldn't your data have an array of the date and the corresponding quantity rather than the full object every time?  You still don't have a [mcve] here; you talk about multiple rows of data but only provided one object with one value when asked.

Comment: I provided one example because everything else looks just the same/every other object has the same properties. I don't understand why I would use an array-every object with the date has only one quantity.

Comment: But do you have more than one "Bowling" object?  Or is every single date all unique fields?  I think I basically understand what you are trying to achieve here, anyway;  I just don't think your title conveys your intent very well.  I am going to spend a bit of time later tonight working on a possible solution.

Comment: this is what I came up with, is it somewhat close to what you are trying to achieve?  http://plnkr.co/edit/AZAEIdLoOOWvmrcKbCXn?p=preview

Comment: Thanks so so much! Thats exactly what I needed and it works great! Could you just explain:   $scope.reservation.selectedProduct.quantity -= $scope.reservation.selectedQuantity;  so I understand it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has a directive built specifically to accomplish this task; `ng-options`.

First, we define an object in the controller that will hold the values selected from the dropdown:

```
$scope.reservation = {};
```

Next, we use ng-options on our dropdowns, and use the `ng-model` property to accept the value selected.  In the first dropdown, we take the array of `products`, display the `dateOfActivity` for each product, and save the `product` object to `ng-model` when selected.  (work from right to left in the `ng-options` definition).

```
ng-model="reservation.selectedProduct"  
ng-options="product as product.dateOfActivity for product in products"
```

In our second dropdown, you have defined a function to take a number and spread it into an array.  We call this function from `reservation.selectedProduct.quantity`, and then use this array as the basis for the `ng-options`:

```
ng-model="reservation.selectedQuantity" 
ng-options="num for num in quantityLister(reservation.selectedProduct.quantity)"
```

Now we have an object which has the selected values for both dropdowns, we just need to change the quantity in the original array on button press.  we also want to clear the selections afterwords, to ensure that the user can't accidentally make a duplicate reservation.

```
$scope.reserve = function (){
  $scope.reservation.selectedProduct.quantity -= $scope.reservation.selectedQuantity;
  $scope.reservation = {};
};
```

Here we use the shorthand `-=` to subtract the `selectedQuantity` from the `selectedProduct.quantity`.  since `selectedProduct` is two way bound, the change to `selectedProduct` is reflected in the original object in the `product` array as well.  However, The `quantityLister` function isn't dynamic;  if we don't reset `$scope.reservation`, the second dropdown would hold a now invalid number of available reservations.